# How can I get CSS scroll snap to work with JS scroll event listener?

Tags: javascript, css

I am working on this project where I need both scroll listeners and scroll-snapping, so I can make some cool transition effects between section changes.

I could get both of these to work separately, but not together. Scroll snapping requires a container element (`main` element) to have a height, but when I give it a `height: 100%`, JavaScript scroll listener stops working.

I tried everything I know, tried changing other containers' height/overflow properties and tried targeting other elements than `body` or `window`. What would be the best workaround be?

The snippet here is adjusted to work with listener at the moment. If you go ahead and add `height: 100%` to `main`, you will see that scroll snapping starts working, but the event listener breaks.

```js
const scrollEvent = () => {
  const main = document.querySelector('#main');
  const section1 = document.querySelector('#sect1');
  const section2 = document.querySelector('#sect2');

  if (main.scrollTop > 50) {
    section1.style.backgroundColor = "red";

  } else {
    section1.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
  }

  if (main.scrollTop > window.innerHeight / 2) {
    section2.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  } else {
    section2.style.backgroundColor = "purple";
  }
}


window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollEvent);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: auto;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

section {
  flex-basis: 100vh;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 90vw;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

main section {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <main id="main" dir="ltr">
    <section id="sect1">
      <h1>content1</h1>
    </section>
    <section id="sect2">
      <h1>content2</h1>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The specific problem is `overflow: auto;` on main. getting rid of that allows it to work.

Comment: I don't see how. With `overflow: auto` gone scroll snaps do not work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In [another topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61759029/css-scroll-snap-not-snapping-on-to-sections/61759410#61759410) @lawrence-witt stated that I had to add the event listener to `main`, instead of whole `window`. With `main.addEventListener('scroll', scrollEvent);` both scroll snap and scroll event listener work fine.

```js
const scrollEvent = () => {
  const main = document.querySelector('#main');
  const section1 = document.querySelector('#sect1');
  const section2 = document.querySelector('#sect2');

  if (main.scrollTop > 50) {
    section1.style.backgroundColor = "red";

  } else {
    section1.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
  }

  if (main.scrollTop > window.innerHeight / 2) {
    section2.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  } else {
    section2.style.backgroundColor = "purple";
  }
}


main.addEventListener('scroll', scrollEvent);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

section {
  flex-basis: 100vh;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 90vw;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

main section {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <main id="main" dir="ltr">
    <section id="sect1">
      <h1>content1</h1>
    </section>
    <section id="sect2">
      <h1>content2</h1>
    </section>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What does *"lawrence-witt stated"* refer to? [This Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61759029/css-scroll-snap-not-snapping-on-to-sections/61759410#61759410)?